# Static Web Page with Map content doesnt work as WebTab or VS Page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, website-integration

Good Day!

> I am trying to create a WebTab Or VS page to display given web link
>   which displays a Map based on Openlayers. There is no interaction
>   intended between salesforce and the map at this point. (The Web link
>   to display: "http://52.27.83.144/GMSC/public/peelchildcare/") I tried
>   creating a WebTab without any merge fields but no avail. Then I tried
>   creating a Visual force page using the code below, tried even
>   downloading the JS and CSS file as static resource but cant figure out
>   whats wrong. Please help! (thinking if creating as Lightning component
>   will help ?)

CODE BEGINS:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="true"  standardStyleSheets="false" controller="ChildCarePublicController">
 <html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
    <title>peelchildcare</title>
       <apex:stylesheet value="/resource/smartPublicMaps/ig.publicmaps.application.min.css" />
        <script src="https://52.27.83.144/GMSC/Public/Content/Scripts/ig.publicmaps.application.min.js"></script>

     <!--    <script src="<a target="_blank" href="" rel="nofollow">https://52.27.83.144/GMSC/Public/Content/Scripts/ig.publicmaps.application.min.js"></script></a>-->


    <script type="text/javascript" id="PublicMapsApplication">
        IG.PublicMaps.application = {"site":"GMSC","projectId":"d74f8831-7ab0-4122-8b41-84980daa73d9","projectName":"peelchildcare","defaultMapViewId":"8b1b832d-8689-437d-94fa-07d5e4fc1c1a","mapViews":[{"id":"8b1b832d-8689-437d-94fa-07d5e4fc1c1a","name":"PeelChildcare","bounds":{"left":-8926829.96,"bottom":5383941.42,"right":-8849031.03,"top":5465620.59},"copyright":null,"center":{"x":-8887930.5,"y":5424781.01},"zoomLevel":"15","isDefault":true,"baseMap":{"type":4,"config":{"zoomLevelCount":20}},"hasMapLayer":false,"hasPoiLayer":true,"hasSearch":false,"searchHint":""}],"symbols":{"90be6f63-bde1-4955-acc7-c9768c33278e":{"isScaleDependent":false,"dimension":{"width":11,"height":11},"dimensions":null}},"baseUrl":"http://52.27.83.144/GMSC/Public/","language":"en-US","isRightToLeft":false};
    </script>
    <style>
#map {
font-family: Arial;
font-size:12px;
line-height:normal !important;
height:250px;
background:transparent;
}
</style></head>
<body ontouchstart="">
    <!--<div> -->
   <div id="ig-publicmaps">

</div>
    <!--</div> -->
</body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

CODE ENDS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that it was the SSL layer and digital certificate not configured and PORT 443 to be opened.
Once that done and changing the HTTP to HTTPS made it worked all fine.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. Can you close this question?